Dependency versions are not updated for Custom repositories
Dependency versions of modules from custom repositories are not automatically updated.
I have a custom repository and a module deployed (0.1.0) in it. I use this module in another Ballerina app as a dependency.
When I deployed the next version 0.1.1 of the module, and try to build the other app which uses this module, the dependency is not updated automatically.
For Ballerina dependencies it happens automatically when there is a latest version.
How can I enable auto version updates to my module?

We have an auto update policy for the packages pushed to the Ballerina Central. However, for the packages pushed to the local/ custom repositories, we do not support auto-updating. For the local/ custom repos, ballerina resolution engine will stick to the exact version specified in the Ballerina.toml. To update a dependency coming from a custom repo, you have to update the entry you have added in the Ballerina.toml
[[dependency]]
org = "your-org-name"
name = "your-pkg-name"
version = "0.1.1" # updated from 0.1.0 to 0.1.1
repository = "nexus_1"

Here, Ballerina will look for 0.1.1 and that only during dependency resolution.
